# Wordpress failed to open stream: No such file or directory, can't open dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Warning:
>   require(/home/bookme08/public_html/sites/laverdad/sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/inc/customizer.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/bookme08/public_html/sites/laverdad/sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/functions.php
>   on line 43
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/bookme08/public_html/sites/laverdad/sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/inc/customizer.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/pear') in
>   /home/bookme08/public_html/sites/laverdad/sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/functions.php
>   on line 43

Trying to figure out any solution to this but have failed. Any support will be highly appreciated.

Also just updated to latest wordpress today deleted plugins, literally no plugins now but still has this error.

Answer (score 2):

Is your theme's folder contains **inc** folder? And it have **customizer.php** file, haven't it? This is not error relevant to plugins or WordPress

Comment: TO my knowledge, i don't remember such folders, what do you recommend that we do?

Comment: Can you navigate to sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/inc to see if any customizer.php file.

Answer (score 2):

This is file missing error. 
Check your customizer.php in 'inc' directory which is located at /home/bookme08/public_html/sites/laverdad/sub.wordpress/g4/wp-content/themes/metro-creativex/inc
This directory surly doesn't have this file. You can copy this file from any defcault theme like 2017 or 2016 if you are using any default theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Musharib, this will be definitely useful. Do you suggest any FTP program and FTP setting for me to navigate the folders of our wordpress account?

Comment: @JustinF You can try FileZilla, it's free and very useful. You just need a FTP account and you can connect to your hosting, no need additional settings.